# transform string in mysql field

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database field `image URL` in which there are image names like `image-0073` but i need to create a URL like `www.xxxxx.com` what i already did with the following code

```
if (isset($result2['img_name'])) {
    $result2['img_name'] = 'http://www.xxxxxx.com/' . $result2['img_name'];
```

But now i have to replace the name of image `image-0073` with new name `www.xxxxx.comimage-0073` in the field `image URL` but don't know how to update that specific field.

Answer (score 0):

Use [**CONCAT**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function

like below :

```
update  tablename set imageURL=CONCAT("www.xxxxx.com',imageURL)
```

Please add conditions and do changes according to your requirments.

Answer (score -1):

```
update table set img_name = concat('http://www.xxxxxx.com/',img_name) where some_field=condition
```

note that if you are going to update every field in the table with no condition, it will make no sense.
I am also have no idea why do you say you want to empty the field.

Answer (score -1):

You can try:

`UPDATE table_name SET field_name = $newImageUrl WHERE img_name = $result2['img_name'];`